# Place JLabel on top of another JLabel, like in a solitaire game

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jlabel

[image]

I have to do a solitaire game using Java and `JFrame` form. I've already managed to add the image of an ace card to the `JLabel`, and to make it change when clicked. What I need to do now is to place one card on top of another similar to the image above. I'm guessing I can do this by creating several labels and placing them on top of each another. The thing's that I don't know how to do it, since every time I create a label it's placed next, on top or below the card.

Comment: something like this [Layered Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html) may be useful

Comment: I think it would be easier to draw the card images where you want them on a JPanel canvas.  Swing components aren't designed to overlap.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc, Swing uses ZOrder when you want components to overlap.

Answer (score 1):

Most layout managers a 2 dimensional. To display components on top of one another you need to start playing with the ZOrder.

Check out the [Overlap Layout](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/26/overlap-layout/) which was designed specifically for this type of layout.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution:

- Create a `BoxLayout` with a vertical orientation. (`BoxLayout.Y_AXIS`) and set that layout to a `JPanel`. This will represent the cards.
- Before you add a `JLabel` to the panel with the `BoxLayout`, create an empty border with a negative top inset. For example: `label.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(-30, 0, 0, 0));` This will cause the label (card) on top to overlap on to the bottom card by that amount. You could play around with the `-30` until you find the right size.

Another possible solution:

- Use a [JLayeredPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html) where the layer level of each card will be in descending order.